# NullPointerException when accessing Boolean Java

Tags: java

I have a `boolean` which checks if an action is to be performed or not, the `boolean` is being being accessed through `setters and getters`, I have other `booleans` am accessing in a similar way and they are not giving me any errors except this one, at first I was checking it in a piece of code within a seperate thread and that part was not working without producing an exception so I put it in a `toggleButton` just to do a simple `read` and `write` on it, then the `nullPointerException` came up, here is my code I have commented it

```
toggleButton.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
         //this part is executing perfectly
         //meaning my toggleButton is ok
         System.out.println("Toggle Button Clicked");

         //this is where I am getting the NullPointerException
         if(!getblackAndWhite()){

            setblackAndWhite(true);

         }else{

              setblackAndWhite(false);

          }
        }});


private void setblackAndWhite(Boolean blackAndWhite)

{
    this.blackAndWhite = blackAndWhite;
}

private Boolean getblackAndWhite()
{
    return this.blackAndWhite;
}
```

Comment: can you post the stackstrace

Comment: add blackAndWhite's declaration! (boolean or Boolean?)

Comment: its been answered thanks

Comment: @WendieLamero Then you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243725).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then `blackAndWhite` is `null` (the default value). Initialize it when you declare it (assuming you want to start with false) that might look something like,

```
private Boolean blackAndWhite = false;
```

**or** in `getblackAndWhite()` check for `null`. Like,

```
public Boolean getblackAndWhite() {
    if (blackAndWhite == null) return false;
    return blackAndWhite;
}
```

Comment: :D you dont say :D I guess I skipped that part of the book that says a boolean should be initialized, i thought it was a simple data type

Comment: Or change to use a primitive boolean type and not the wrapper type. The primitive has a default value of false to start with, so if you forget to initialize it defaults to false and you can avoid the NPE.

Comment: @WendieLamero `boolean` is a primitive type, it's default value (as an instance variable) is `false`. `Boolean` is a reference type, it's default value (as an instance variable) is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not setting the value of `blackAndWhite` in your constructor and you call `getblackAndWhite()` before it is set you will get a null pointer exception (NPE)

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is an object. Is it initialised?